Convert Sas character date yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm to DDMMMYYYY HH:MM
In my ADaM dataset,I have character date (ex: 2022-12-11T21:57). I am working on a listing where I need to display the date as DDMMMYYYY HH:MM (ex : 11DEC2022 21:57). In the listing I need to concatenate this date with another date with similar format hence it needs to be in character value. What would be the most efficient way to do this?
I tried splitting the date into date and time by using substr function. And then tried formatting it to date 9. Its not working.
I didn't notice before, but I see that my data also has dates only in addition to date and time(For example : 2023-05-30 , 2022-12-11T21:57). Is there a format I can use instead of e8601dt. that will consider time and /or date)?
I would like my output to be 30MAY2023 , 11DEC2022 21:57.

Show the code you tried. Note that the values you show are DATETIME (number of seconds) and not DATE (number of days).  Do you need to values converted into actual datetime values so they can be used in calculations?  Or do you just need to generate another string?  Show an example of what you are trying to create.

To convert that string into a datetime value you can use the E8601DT informat.  If you display it with the DATETIME format you will get something like 11DEC2022:21:57:00.  If you must have the string without the seconds and with a space separating the date from the time of day then you will probably need to build it yourself.  You could use the DTDATE9. and TOD5. formats to generate the two parts.
Example:
1    data test;
2      string1='2022-12-11T21:57';
3      datetime=input(string1,e8601dt.);
4      format datetime datetime19.;
5      length string2 $15 ;
6      string2=cat(put(datetime,dtdate9.),' ',put(datetime,tod5.));
7      put (_all_) (=/);
8    run;


string1=2022-12-11T21:57
datetime=11DEC2022:21:57:00
string2=11DEC2022 21:57

